# How to assign or initialize a Java array to Javascript array, without using JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, playframework

I am working in Play framework and I need to use Java array inside Javascript.

I tried the following -

```
var jsarray = ${javaArray};
```

Where `javaArray` is the array in the Java controller, being rendered to the HTML view.

But, it is not working. Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget you're not passing variables... You're writing javascript code

So, you have to make your array rendering nicely for Javascript

```
var jsArray = [%{javaArray.eachWithIndex{it,idx->
                 }%
                 ${it}${(idx<javaArray.size()-1)?",":""}
                 %{
                 }
                 }%]
```

Use something that fits with your template engine. You have to iterate through your array then prints out the values on the view

PS : I've used the Groovy notation...

Comment: I don't know if Play/Scala will do it automatically with the .each function, but you need to comma separate each array value.

Comment: I was editing the post to say that... You should test the end of the array to not add the last comma
thanks for spotting :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot... It worked for me... Since I am using a string array, I need to modify the above as "${it}" - (added "")